# Weekly/recurring option in Flash AS3? Like A weekly recurrence in a calendar?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, date, date-range

All I am trying to do is write a piece of code that will auto jump through a specified number of weeks, week by week.  **For instance, start on 11/28/2011, and spit out each weeks date until 11/26/2012.**  I'm trying this from scratch because to my understanding, the date() class pulls it information starting from the system date.

Essentially, **making something recur each week is what I'm looking for** but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.  I've tried using a piece of code I wrote that jumps weeks on a swipe, but it pulls from the date class so that's not working for me.  I've searched EVERYWHERE for the past 7-8 days online and can't find anything.  I can provide code if you need it, but I think it may just confuse you cause it's a lot and it's essential wrong to begin with...

Just even a push in the write direction should be enough cause I lost in that sense even lol...thanks

Comment: Just to add, I'm not looking for anything to update weekly, just to report each date until it meets the set limit...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understood your question, I would do the following and take advantage of being able to add days to the date property of the Date object:

```
var currentDate:Date = new Date(2011,11,28);
var endDate:Date = new Date(2012,11,26);
while(currentDate < endDate){
    currentDate.date += 7;
    //Do whatever you have planned for each date/week here
    trace(currentDate.toString());   
}
```

PS: the date class' default constructor `Date()` will return the current system time; however, if you pass it additional params you can create a Date object for any valid date.

Comment: mother *beep*...I can't believe I forgot about that...gonna try it right now lol.  EDIT - WOW!  THAT FREAKIN EASY!!! I feel bad I even asked the question now lol...I hope others weren't pulling their hair out over something simple like that like I was.  Thank you so much for that...now I can sleep lol